# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 Xcode 7

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I recently updated my Xcode from 6 to 7 and now I am getting this error that I can't figure out how to solve.

```
class usersVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView!

    var resultsNameArray = [String]()
    var resultsUserNameArray = [String]()
    var resultsImageFiles = [PFFile]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
        let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

        resultsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


        resultsNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultsUserNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultsImageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let query = PFUser.query()

        query!.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                for object in objects! {

                    self.resultsNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as! String)
                    self.resultsImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)
                    self.resultsUserNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)

                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()


                }

            }

        }

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return resultsNameArray.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 64

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:usersCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! usersCell

        cell.profileLbl.text = self.resultsNameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.usernameLbl.text = self.resultsUserNameArray[indexPath.row]

        let query = PFQuery(className: "follow")

        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        query.whereKey("userToFollow", equalTo: cell.usernameLbl.text!)

        query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (count:Int32, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if count == 0 {

                    cell.followBtn.setTitle("Follow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                } else {

                    cell.followBtn.setTitle("UnFollow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                }

            }

        }


        self.resultsImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.imgView.image = image

            }

        }

        return cell

    }

}
```

This is the error:

```
1.  While type-checking 'viewDidAppear' at /Users/daniellemurray/Desktop/CurlspectiveApp 5/twitterApp/usersVC.swift:36:14
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/daniellemurray/Desktop/CurlspectiveApp 5/twitterApp/usersVC.swift:47:9 - line:65:9] RangeText="query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                for object in objects! {

                    self.resultsNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as! String)
                    self.resultsImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)
                    self.resultsUserNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)

                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()


                }

            }

        }"
3.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/daniellemurray/Desktop/CurlspectiveApp 5/twitterApp/usersVC.swift:47:9 - line:65:9] RangeText="query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                for object in objects! {

                    self.resultsNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as! String)
                    self.resultsImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)
                    self.resultsUserNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)

                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()


                }

            }

        }"
4.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/daniellemurray/Desktop/CurlspectiveApp 5/twitterApp/usersVC.swift:47:49 - line:65:9] RangeText="{
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                for object in objects! {

                    self.resultsNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as! String)
                    self.resultsImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)
                    self.resultsUserNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)

                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()


                }

            }

        }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

to

```
query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

Reference link from [github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/280)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error while working with Parse and Xcode Version 7.0.1. Try removing the explicit type declarations from the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock call.  So this

```
query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

becomes this

```
query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects, error) -> Void in
```